# Unable to deploy rails app to production (Could not detect rake tasks error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I have a working app in localhost and now that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku, I get an error during deployment and the git does not commit to heroku. At first it seemed like the issue was bootsnap, so I removed that, but now it's something else and I'm at a loss to figure out what's going on. I also tried updating the bundler to match the one that is supported by heroku with no luck. The error from the git push is below:

```
remote:        Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- ap
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/Rakefile:5:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: LoadError: cannot load such file -- ap
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/Rakefile:5:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_c760f38864f8aa8f1edc0cd499cc9c93/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `load'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:17:in `<main>'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:860:in `rake'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:79:in `has_jobs_work_task?'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:53:in `block in default_process_types'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:46:in `default_process_types'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:29:in `block in default_process_types'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:23:in `default_process_types'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:26:in `block in default_process_types'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:25:in `default_process_types'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:104:in `write_release_yaml'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:82:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:114:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:92:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:134:in `log'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'

remote:         from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to smarthost-demo.
remote:
To heroku.com:smarthost-demo.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:smarthost-demo.git'
```

bundle exec rake -P RAILS_ENV=production:

```
rake about
    environment
rake active_storage:install
    environment
rake active_storage:install:migrations
rake app:template
    environment
rake app:templates:copy
rake app:update
    update:configs
    update:bin
    update:upgrade_guide_info
rake app:update:bin
rake app:update:configs
rake app:update:upgrade_guide_info
rake assets:clean
    environment
rake assets:clobber
    environment
rake assets:environment
rake assets:precompile
    environment
    yarn:install
rake autoprefixer:info
rake cache_digests:dependencies
    environment
rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies
    environment
rake db:_dump
rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations
    load_config
rake db:charset
    load_config
rake db:check_protected_environments
    load_config
rake db:collation
    load_config
rake db:create
    load_config
rake db:create:all
    load_config
rake db:drop
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:drop:_unsafe
    load_config
rake db:drop:all
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:environment:set
    load_config
rake db:fixtures:identify
    load_config
rake db:fixtures:load
    load_config
rake db:forward
    load_config
rake db:load_config
    environment
rake db:migrate
    load_config
rake db:migrate:down
    load_config
rake db:migrate:redo
    load_config
rake db:migrate:reset
    db:drop
    db:create
    db:migrate
rake db:migrate:status
    load_config
rake db:migrate:up
    load_config
rake db:purge
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:purge:all
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:reset
    db:drop
    db:setup
rake db:rollback
    load_config
rake db:schema:cache:clear
    load_config
rake db:schema:cache:dump
    load_config
rake db:schema:dump
    load_config
rake db:schema:load
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:schema:load_if_ruby
    db:create
    environment
rake db:seed
rake db:sessions:clear
    environment
    db:load_config
rake db:sessions:create
    environment
    db:load_config
rake db:sessions:trim
    environment
    db:load_config
rake db:setup
    db:schema:load_if_ruby
    db:structure:load_if_sql
    seed
rake db:structure:dump
    load_config
rake db:structure:load
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:structure:load_if_sql
    db:create
    environment
rake db:test:load
    db:test:purge
rake db:test:load_schema
    db:test:purge
rake db:test:load_structure
    db:test:purge
rake db:test:prepare
    load_config
rake db:test:purge
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:version
    load_config
rake default
    test
rake dev:cache
rake environment
rake initializers
    environment
rake log:clear
rake middleware
    environment
rake notes
rake notes:custom
rake notes:fixme
rake notes:optimize
rake notes:todo
rake railties:install:migrations
    db:load_config
rake restart
rake routes
    environment
rake secret
rake stats
rake test
rake test:controllers
    test:prepare
rake test:db
    db:test:prepare
    test
rake test:functionals
    test:prepare
rake test:generators
    test:prepare
rake test:helpers
    test:prepare
rake test:integration
    test:prepare
rake test:jobs
    test:prepare
rake test:mailers
    test:prepare
rake test:models
    test:prepare
rake test:prepare
rake test:run
    test
rake test:system
    test:prepare
rake test:units
    test:prepare
rake time:zones
rake time:zones:all
rake time:zones:local
rake time:zones:us
rake tmp
rake tmp/cache
rake tmp/cache/assets
rake tmp/pids
rake tmp/sockets
rake tmp:cache:clear
rake tmp:clear
    tmp:cache:clear
    tmp:sockets:clear
    tmp:screenshots:clear
rake tmp:create
    tmp/cache
    tmp/sockets
    tmp/pids
    tmp/cache/assets
rake tmp:pids:clear
rake tmp:screenshots:clear
rake tmp:sockets:clear
rake yarn:install
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is "LoadError: cannot load such file -- ap".

This means you probably have a `require 'ap'` in your Rakefile, but awesome_print is not being installed in production.

Ensure that you are not requiring non-production gems in your Rakefile or update your Gemfile to move awesome_print out of your :development group.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't have awesome print specifically called out anywhere. I did a couple of things for it to work, first, I noticed devise was causing an implicit error on rake because a variable was not yet set. This wasn't a problem in localhost, but it was in heroku. After doing this, I re-ran rake assets:precompile. The devise.rb rake fix plus the command below, may have fixed the  `'ap'` file references. After this, the deployment finally succeeded.

Comment: Can you please let me know the exact commands that you have ran to fix the issue?